# How can I pass a touch through a view in React Native but trigger the onPress?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a full screen touchable view that gets its `onPress` triggered but also passes the touch down to the view behind it. In the example below, I'd like to have the `onPress` function get called when the user scrolls on the scrollview. I'm able to get the scrollview to respond with `pointerEvents="none"` on the `Pressable`, but doing that makes the `onPress` not get triggered. Is there any way to get both of these working together?

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containingTouchable: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(100,100,100,0.3)',
  },
});

const Component = () => {
  <Pressable
      style={styles.containingTouchable}
      onPress={() => {
        console.warn('pressed me');
      }}
  >
    <View></View>
  </Pressable>
  <ScrollView> ... </ScrollView>
}
```

Comment: I think you have to remove reactjs tag for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this using `react-native-gesture-handler`. Instead of `Pressable`, use `TapGestureHandler`. And import `ScrollView` from `react-native-gesture-handler`.

Rngh provides a prop called `simultaneousHandlers` so you can listen to multiple touch event at once.

So you could do something like this:

```js
const tapGestureHandlerRef = useRef(null);

<TapGestureHandler
    ref={tapGestureHandlerRef}
    onActivated={handleOnPress}
    onHandlerStateChange={handleOnPress}
>
    <ScrollView
     simultaneousHandlers={tapGestureHandlerRef}
    > 
        {content}
    </ScrollView>
  </TapGestureHandler
>
```

Both `onActivated` and `onHandlerStateChange` can trigger an onPress event, but they behave differently. Take a look at the docs to see what fits your use case the best: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/gesture-handlers/tap-gh